# How to configure arquillian-drone to disable JavaScript in Firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone

I want to run my test in Firefox **with JavaScript disabled**, so I create a qualifier:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Qualifier
public @interface FirefoxWithoutJS
{

}
```

And I add the extension in the file `arquillina.xml`:

```
<extension qualifier="webdriver-firefoxwithoutjs">
    <property name="browser">firefox</property>
    <property name="firefox_binary">PathToThefirefox.exe</property>
    <!-- I guess I should add something here -->
</extension>
```

Surely, this configuration will not disable JavaScript, can you give me an example about how to do that?

I use:

- Gradle 2.3
- arquillian-junit-container 1.1.8
- arquillian-drone 2.0.0
- Selenium 2.45.0

Answer (score 2):

To configure browser capabilities, you have to add them as properties in the extension's configuration.

Try adding the below property:

`<property name="javascriptEnabled">false</property>`